# Can a C++ Header file with classes be converted to a Delphi unit?

Tags: c++, delphi, header-files

I have a C++ *.h file with three classes in it.  The header file is for accessing a DLL.  I have almost no C++ knowledge.  However, I seem to recall from somewhere that you can't convert a *.h file to a Delphi unit that has classes in it.  Is this true?

If it isn't true, and classes in header files aren't a problem, what is the general approach to converting the classes to Delphi?

Comment: Convert in the sense of creating a semantically similar, but distinct Delphi class, or convert in the sense of allowing Delphi to (for example) invoke C++ methods on C++ objects via a FFI?

Comment: Convert as in allowing me to use the DLL in question.  I'll amend the question, which didn't include that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sense of allowing you to use the DLL from Delphi code?  Yeah, good luck with that.  You know how you can't use Delphi classes in a DLL unless the client code is written in the same version of Delphi and even then it's usually a bad idea due to shared memory management gotchas?  C++ poses *exactly the same problem,* only exponentially worse because there's no standardized ABI and there's all sorts of C++-language screwed-uppedness making problems for you.

The only real way to make it work reliably is with an interface that uses a standard ABI.  If you have the source, try making a C interface that wraps the C++ interface.  If not, ask the person who wrote the DLL to provide a C interface, and ask whoever made the decision to use this DLL why you're using a 3rd party library with no source available. :P

Comment: Thanks, Mason --- that is pretty much what I thought.   I have the source for the header file obviously, but not the DLL.  I will ask, though.  Maybe they'll include it.

Comment: It's not exponentially worse in fact. It's just the same. Otherwise I agree with everything else you wrote.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It would be, except C++ has objects-as-value-types, which introduces all kinds of new hassles that Delphi code (or just about any other OO language ever, because it's a horrible idea that no one else within epsilon re-used) never has to deal with, particularly if you're working with polymorphism.

Comment: @Mason That's a pain in the backside, true, but it's a side issue here. Delphi forces all modules to be built with same compiler, linked against same dynamic runtime. It's the same situation with C++.

Comment: FWIW shared memory is easy to overcome. The real issue with classes across DLL boundaries is the lack of class identity, and the lack of a shared runtime. So DLL1.TObject is a different class from DLL2.TObject.

Comment: I wonder why this answer, and mine, have been downvoted. Since the two answers say much the same thing, I suspect the same person to have cast both votes. It would be nice to know what is wrong with the answers.

Answer (score 8):

C++ classes, just like Delphi classes, are not designed for binary interop.

A Delphi class can only be exported for consumption by other Delphi code, and then only in a package, and only when runtime packages are in use, and only when all modules use the same version of Delphi. In a similar vein, C++ classes can only be imported from a DLL by code compiled with the same tool chain that compiled the DLL.

So, it is not possible for your Delphi code to consume this DLL. As I see it you have the following options:

1. Persuade the supplier of the DLL to provide an interop friendly interface to the library. For instance, a plain functional C style interface, or a COM interface.
2. Write an adapter in C++, using the same compiler that was used to build the DLL. That would involve you importing the classes into your wrapper and exposing them to your Delphi code in an interop friendly manner. Again, plain C style interface or COM are the obvious choices.

Comment: +1. Also read Rudy's article [Using C++ objects in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html)

Comment: There are tools such as [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/compare.html)  that can be used to generate wrappers for C++ code. Unfortunately, while SWIG supports 20 languages (including Modula-3), Delphi is not one of them. I know there was some support among the FreePascal folks for adding Pascal support to SWIG, but nothing came of that. I don't know of any other wrapper generator that has Delphi support right now. :-(

Comment: "Persuade the supplier of the DLL to provide an interop friendly interface to the library. For instance, a plain functional C style interface, or a COM interface." Reminds me of a quote: "This makes it possible to pass complex object hierarchies to a C coder who thinks computer science has made no worthwhile advancements since the invention of the pointer." - Gordon McMillan

Comment: Just as an aside, reading this made me think, "why isn't there a standard means of exporting and importing objects as character streams, like via XML or JSON, built into every class by default?" I think the RTTI in both C++ Builder and Delphi is sufficient to allow most classes to be described, exchanged, and instantiated dynamically. Of course, that doesn't help with stuff from other vendors, and it certainly would be slower than a pure binary interface. But it sure would simplify working with DLLs a lot!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It would be a lot easier if Delphi's fundamental data types were objects themselves; in some languages done this way what you describe (ability to serialize) does exist. There's serialization/marshaling with JSON in Delphi Datasnap - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Serializing_User_Objects , but it seems ridiculously complex for even what seems to me to be a trivial example.

Comment: @David COM is a standard for binary interop of objects that works exceptionally well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the context here is about passing classes between different language interfaces, which COM does not support.

Comment: @alcalde I've never used anything but the Professional Edition of Delphi, so I have no experience with DataSnap.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, the context is binary interop. COM is the platform standard solution to this problem. Serialization with, for instance, JSON or XML deals with data. How are you going to call methods of objects in a different module using JSON?

Comment: Protocols, protocols!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The scenario that Nick describes in the question is a DLL that exports classes. I don't see any protocols.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The JSON serialization is included in the datasnap library but from what I can see doesn't involve Datasnap proper. I think it's just something they reserve for the Enterprise edition to justify the higher price. :-) I've been told that there are simpler/more powerful 3rd party serialization libraries than what's found in the Ent. edition. I do agree with your suggestion; on a wish list I had of Delphi features full built-in serialization was one of the main features.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan COM is a Windows-only solution that's not exactly regarded as elegant. David Schwartz is talking about a language feature like Java's Remote Method Invocation or maybe Python's Pyro.

Comment: @alcalde Windows DLLs are a Windows only solution.

Answer (score 1):

As commented in a previous answer the solution is using SWIG in order to generate the pascal binding. I started the development of the SWIG's pascal module but I had not time to complete it. Basically it works but it lacks all the test cases to be integrated into SWIG.

I used it in my personal projects and I was able to import complex library as GDAL.

Comment: No amount of SWIG can get over the fact that Delphi code cannot instantiate and destroy C++ objects, or call their methods. You presumably were binding against the C API of GDAL, an altogether different proposition. Or getting SWIG to generate C wrappers which you compiled and then consumed from Delphi.

Comment: The SWIG module does 1) flatten the C++ into plain C stubs - the stubs must be compiled in a DLL (I use VS for this task); 2) generate pascal import unit; 3) generate Pascal classes invoking the C stubs in the Pascal's methods implementation

Comment: That's not clear from the answer. A naive reader might assume that you are claiming that SWIG can let you call the original C++ DLL and consume the classes. So that might be worth making clear in your answer. Essentially you are offering the observation that SWIG can be used to help create a wrapper.